# Ramifications of voltage imbalance in a 3-phase motor

Tags: three-phase, unbalanced

I have a 2.2 kW, 3-phase motor running a high pressure compressor. The supply mains voltage is very unbalanced.  P1 221 V, P2 185 V, and P3 220 V under load (it should be 240 V).

This is a 3rd world country and I have no ability to correct the voltage drop from the energy provider.

Interelated questions:

- I understand the motor will experience an increase in vibration, heat and current. All bad things. But how bad? I need to run this equipment; will it be destroyed? How quickly? Or will it just not be efficient?
- Is there a cost-effective "magic box" I could install to fix the voltage unbalance?

Any constructive feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: So a UPS that  is charged by the supply and delvers clean controlled power to your device. We acquired an 11kW UPS that we used to run the power for all out IT equipment. Was fantastic.

Comment: @SolarMike that's a large expense - even larger in a 3rd-world country!

Comment: I *think* it's possible to voltage-regulate each phase separately, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: @user253751 it was given to us FREE - all we had to do was disconnect, remove and then connect it. The building had to be cleared and nobody wanted to touch it...

Comment: @SolarMike good for you, but SV Savannah probably isn't so lucky.

Comment: A *variable-frequency-drive* is another common-ish piece of equipment that could correct this, since it does AC->DC->AC conversion. If you happen to have a spare one. Don't quote me on that either.

Comment: Engineering alternatives are > opinions.

Comment: IF the voltages are constant then 1. The provider may be able to balance the load better if you ask nicely. 2. Tapped or variable  Autotransformers could be used to adjust phase voltages.but it is unlikely to be cost effective.

Comment: Interest only - what country are you in? [I'm in New Zealand].

Comment: I am in Indonesia